# Sftp Batch script on Windows OS to detect success/failure

Tags: batch-file, sftp

How do I run `sftp` Batch script on Windows OS to detect success/failure?

I use `%errorlevel%` to detect success/failure, but the `%errorlevel%` can be returned by `0` despite the session is failed and the file is not uploaded to the server.

My script is below:

```
sftp2 -D4 -B ftp.txt %dest%
set result=%errorlevel%
if result EQU 0 (
   echo successful
) else (
   echo unsuccessful
)
exit %result%

Content of ftp.txt
put ABC.TXT
QUIT
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
if result EQU 0 (
```

to

```
if %result% EQU 0 (
```